# Bootstrap modal in for loop

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I'm iterating over multi modals using a for loop in django template but the modal worked only for the first element of the list. I've modified id values in `<a href=...>` and `<div class="modal fade">` to change with the loop as suggested in [Bootstrap modal, django for loop and model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032486/bootstrap-modal-django-for-loop-and-model) and [multi modals bootstrap in for loop django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777410/multi-modals-bootstrap-in-for-loop-django). Still not working.

Any suggestions ?
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
{% for sess in session %}        
   <a href="#{{ sess.id }}" role="button" class="btn btn-fix text-left p-0" data-toggle="modal">Link</a>
   <div class="modal fade" id="{{ sess.id }}" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
             <div class="modal-content">
                     <h5>{{sess.Title}}</h5>
                     <p class="text-right">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     </p>
             </div>
         </div>
   </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know why: The id value in the button & modal should not be anumber (so not `{{sess.id}}`). It's working with `test{{sess.id}}` though.